# Trouble using sunspot with pins on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm trying to implement sunspot while using pins on rails.

When I run `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex` for sunspot

I get an error saying:

```
rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: pins: SELECT  "pins".* FROM "pins"   ORDER BY "pins"."id" ASC LIMIT 50
```

What maybe the problem here, and how can I fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: doesn't work:( 
a better solution?

Comment: Did you run `rails generate sunspot_rails:install`? If you did did you `bundle exec rake db:migrate` afterward? If you are using solr, did you `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`?